# Three Questions with Twenty Eleven theme

Tags: php, post-thumbnails, logo, images, theme-twenty-eleven

I have a few things that I need help with in Twenty Eleven.

1. The logo I put in the header is resized to 578px by 160px, when it is supposed to be 326px by 90px.
2. I would like to simply the php code that controls this:
   http://i55.tinypic.com/33tsehh.jpg

I added the gradient to the info box and also the about the author text and bio line. I'm not very knowledgeable with PHP so I don't want to mess with it without help.

```
<?php
        /* translators: used between list items, there is a space after the comma */
        $categories_list = get_the_category_list( __( ', ', 'twentyeleven' ) );


        /* translators: used between list items, there is a space after the comma */
        $tag_list = get_the_tag_list( '', __( ', ', 'twentyeleven' ) );
        if ( '' != $tag_list ) {
            $utility_text = __( 'This entry was posted in %1$s and tagged %2$s by <a href="%6$s">%5$s</a>.', 'twentyeleven' );
        } elseif ( '' != $categories_list ) {
            $utility_text = __( 'This entry was posted in %1$s by <a href="%6$s">%5$s</a>. Bookmark the <a href="%3$s" title="Permalink to %4$s" rel="bookmark">permalink</a>.', 'twentyeleven' );
        } else {
            $utility_text = __( 'This entry was posted by <a href="%6$s">%5$s</a>. Bookmark the <a href="%3$s" title="Permalink to %4$s" rel="bookmark">permalink</a>.', 'twentyeleven' );
        }


        printf(
            $utility_text,
            $categories_list,
            $tag_list,
            esc_url( get_permalink() ),
            the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ),
            get_the_author(),
            esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) )
        );
    ?>
```

1. I want to know how I could add a featured image for each post to the front page because it doesn't seem like it has one coded in.

Here is a live link: http://gscdesigns.co.cc/
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Adding a post thumbnail is pretty easy, open content.php, if you're using excerpts on your homepage find this

`<?php the_excerpt(); ?>`

then add this just above that line

`<?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', 'class=alignleft'); ?>`

If you're not using excerpts add it above

`<?php the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentyeleven' ) ); ?>`

If you'd like a specific image size for your post thumbnails you can add something like this to functions.php, change 140, 140 to whatever size you want.

`add_image_size('excerpt-thumbnail', 140, 140, true);`

Then change

`<?php the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', 'class=alignleft'); ?>`

To

`<?php the_post_thumbnail('excerpt-thumbnail', 'class=alignleft'); ?>`

Then just add a featured image to a post. It's best to do this with by creating a child theme.

Not sure what you're asking for the first two questions, maybe you could explain them a little more.